# Leer y escribir un archivo ini de configuraciones

Tags: php

He estado investigando sin obtener un resultado satisfactorio sobre como leer un archivo `config.ini` que tengo en mi proyecto para posteriormente escribirlo, el mismo almacena las configuraciones para conexión a la base de datos;

Puedo leerlo con `parse_ini_file()`

```
<?php return; ?>
host=localhost
user=postgres
pass=1706
dbname=mydb
driver=pgsql
port=5432
charset=utf8
collation=utf8_general_ci
prefix=""
```

Quiero escribir mediante php nuevos valores en este archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la librería [Config_Lite](http://pear.php.net/package/Config_Lite).

Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo se usa:

```
<?php

require_once 'Config/Lite.php';

$config = new Config_Lite(); // Creamos el objeto

$config->read('config.ini'); // Abrimos el archivo

echo $config; // Para imprimir el archivo

$config->set(null, 'host', '127.0.0.1')  // Editamos valores
       ->set(null, 'user', 'miusuario');

echo $config; // Volvemos a imprimir

$config->save(); // Guardamos el archivo
```

Aquí hay [ejemplos más detallados](https://github.com/pear/Config_Lite/blob/master/docs/examples) si los necesitas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, le echare un ojo

Comment: Excelente, esta librería es justo lo que buscaba, he logrado escribir de una forma muy sencilla en el archivo. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Saludos puedes usar **parse_ini_file**.

Supongamos mi ini algo asi:

```
server = 'localhost'
password = '123456'
```

en tu php lo lees de la siguiente forma:

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("mi_archivo.ini");
print_r($ini_array); # imprime todo el archivo parseado

print($ini_array['server']); #imprime "localhost"
```

[Mayor detalle aca en la Documentación](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

Suerte y espero te sirva..!!

Comment: Gracias, pero ya tengo acceso al archivo y efectivamente uso la funcion `parse_ini_file()`